# ReaderWriterLock Class not supported in winRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, c#-5.0

I have to use ReaderWriterLock Class and I am unable to find any helping material from Google. please describe how can I achieve this functionality in winRT.

Comment: Use ReaderWriterLockSlim instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Check this article:
https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/iblogger/2013/01/14/concurrency-winrt-observablecollection-and-iteration/.